# JAVASCRIPT - Need to understand the script

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I am new to programming or scripting. I recently started taking 101 courses for JavaScript and SQL so I have a hard time understanding statements. Our company uses a Health Information System where we can use javascript to control some of the field behaviors in the forms.

One of the forms I am working on have Time Duration fields where its sums gets pulled into a field. The field have this Javascipt statement as a default value.

```
VBFormatTimeDuration((formAction !='ADD' ? getDataValue('event_view', 'event_log_id', keyValue, 'duration_total') : '0')
```

I am assuming that this is a conditional statement with ternary operators... I cant seem to get some of its parts. It also seems like its calling a SQL view and a column from a table...

Can someone help me understand this statement?

Thanks,

Daryl

Answer (score 0):

You 'r right,
Its a ternary,

```
(formAction !='ADD' ? getDataValue('event_view', 'event_log_id', keyValue, 'duration_total') : '0')
```

Means

```
if(formAction !='ADD')
   getDataValue('event_view', 'event_log_id', keyValue, 'duration_total') 
else
   '0'
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming. What I dont understand are some of the functions and variables that was used... "!=ADD" - the goals is to get the sum so I dont understand why use not equal. event_view might be an SQL view, event_log_id seems like a column from a table, duration_total is the name of the field, but I don't know what keyValue is? Also formAction and DataValue - are those variables or functions?